# finger draw not working in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, ios5, draw, quartz-graphics

I've been on this for a few days now, trying several things but still stuck in it. Hoping I can understand what's wrong and a possible solution for it, this is kind of getting me crazy at the moment. I thank in advance anyone helping out.

**The Context**: I am working on a demo (with that meaning not yet an app, just a proof of concept) for a blackboard. StackOverflow won't let me post images in questions, for 'spam prevention' reasons, so I am trying to link my Dropbox account to show pics. Please see this:

https://www.dropbox.com/gallery/5189052/1/so?h=8573b1

You can see the blackboard in portrait mode in image 1.

**The problem**: I actually have two problems.

The first is that the drawing seems to work well in portrait mode, however when I switch 
    to landscape mode the drawing area does not seem to reflect the different size.

The second is that I don't seem to be able to enforce the bounds of the drawing area, although the UIImageView containing the blackboard has the correct (i.e. non-overlapping with the bar above it) size. This happens in both portrait and landscape modes.

You can see both issues in image 2 on the previous link; the draw stops right where it would stop in portrait mode, and it also draws on the bar with colours and rubber.

**The Code**: below is the code for the selectors handling touches. I also attach, in image 3 from the link above, a shot about the structure of my nib file.

```
//viewDidLoad in MyViewController.m. DrawImage is the UIImageView containing the board
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
drawImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil];
drawImage.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view addSubview:drawImage];

mouseMoved = 0;
colorCode = 1;

red = 1.0;
green = 1.0;
blue = 1.0;

}


//touchesBegan in MyViewController.m
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        mouseSwiped = NO;

        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

        if([touch tapCount] == 2) {
            drawImage.image = nil;

            return;
        }

        lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
}


//touchesMoved in MyViewController.m
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
mouseSwiped = YES;

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 4.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);

CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);

CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

lastPoint = currentPoint;

mouseMoved++;

if (mouseMoved == 10) {
    mouseMoved = 0;
}

}


//touchesEnded in MyViewController.m
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
    drawImage.image = nil;
    return;
}


if(!mouseSwiped) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
}
```

**What I have tried**: before posting, I have tried a few things. I noticed that when in landscape mode the coordinates changing are bounds rather than frame. For instance whereas self.view.frame.width and height stay on 320 and 480 respectively in portrait and landscape, bounds change to 480 and 320 when in landscape. I thus tried to base my paths and rects on bounds, but unfortunately I start having (apparently) weird drawings with strange coordinates.

I've got the feeing the reason why I can't enforce the correct bounds on the draw lies in the fact that the drawing area is determined over the frame of the main view, which stretches across the whole window. I tried to insert the UIImageView containing the board within a further view (with the right size) and link it to an outlet defined on MyViewController.h, but unfortunately that didn't change any of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In touchesMoved: method you can put a condition to detect wether the touch is on UIImageView containing blackboard or its a different view .If its not blackboard view return it without drawing the image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not entirely clear how to check what view the touch is on, nor why I would want to check it. In my code I draw a rect on self.view, I would imagine that is the view the touch is on?

Thanks again.

Comment: you are setting drawImage frame to the self.view and then drawing on it.My suggestion is that ,start your frame with some y+100 value of drawImage and then draw only blackboard on it.The remaining duster and color selections u can put as buttons on self.view on the top of drawImage,then you can easily identify where touch is happening.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm a bit confused...
I tried what I believe I understand from your suggestion. I set

    drawImage.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 320, 480);

and as a result the lines I draw result shifted in the capacity of those coordinates. I'd guess that means it is actually drawing on DrawImage?

Cheers.

Comment: you can say so(but its not like that ,you are passing the whole screens frame as context..it can draw in the whole that area)..but you have to modify your code to understand better.just read how UIGraphicsBeginImageContext things work from iOS Documentation

Comment: Hang on...how is UIGraphicsBeginImageContext related to setting drawImage.frame to self.view.frame?

Answer (score -1):

I finally tackled the issue in the way suggested in Apple documentation; I created a landscape view controller and let the portrait on transit to this.
Works pretty well.